# Is a quadratic function always convex in a quadratic program (QP)?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, hessian-matrix, quadratic-programming

If you have a quadratic objective function, is this always convex (or concave)? It sounds logical as you think of the shape of a parabola. However, I read that the Hessian can be negative-definite and then the quadratic function is non-convex. Can someone clarify this and maybe give some examples?

Comment: Is the quadratic function $x^2-y^2$ convex on $\mathbb{R}^2$? Concave?

Comment: It's not convex, because the Hessian is negative definite (eigenvalues are 2 and -2).

Comment: So a quadratic program is not per definition convex?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Also, the Hessian is not negative definite. It is indefinite.

Comment: Is it because the beneath holds?:
If all the eigenvalues are nonnegative, it is positive semidefinite.

If all the eigenvalues are positive, it is positive definite.

If all the eigenvalues are nonpositive, it is negative semidefinite.

If all the eigenvalues are negative, it is negative definite.

Otherwise, it is indefinite.

Moreover, I think most of the times a quadratic program is convex, right?

Comment: Yes, your understanding of an indefinite matrix is correct. However, not all quadratic programs are convex. When a quadratic program is convex, then we specify it explicitly by calling it a convex quadratic program.